# Android Studio 2.3 cannot install emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm new to android and I'm confused with this error.
**`Android studio 2.3`** 
Tried to install emulator but it stucked and does not download.

error view

[image]

I wanted to create a AVD and with the steps it showed this error.

This is the previous view in AVD. I clicked "install emulator" link to download it.

AVD view

[image: image2]

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

try downloading what you need through Android Studio built-in SDK Manager.

on Windows: **File > Settings**

on Mac OSX: **Android Studio > Preferences**

then type "Android SDK" in search bar (or "SDK" or "manager")

you will see the SDK Manager

[image]

check **Show Package Details** on the bottom right

then choose the System Image you need, click ok and proceed with installation

next time you enter AVD Manager, your system image should be available to pick up